# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 - Add CSS to CMS Page of Module

Tags: css, module, content-management-system, prestashop

I am making a module that adds new tab in product edit page. The installation is Prestashop 1.6.1.4. The module adds a tab with some input fields that send data to mysql tables, but what I want to do is to style the fields a little bit, so that they look good. I am adding this in my module.php file:

```
public function install() {
    if ($this->psversion() == 5 || $this->psversion() == 6)
    {
        if (parent::install() == false or !$this->registerHook('displayHeader') or !$this->registerHook('productFooter') or !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra') or !$this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate') or !$this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then below this I put this code:

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader($params) {
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/adminsportsnutritionfadd.css');
}
```

But can't make the .css file appear. The file is in the right location, it has proper permissions and the owner of the file is www-data:www-data so this shouldn't be a permission issue. I have disable css combining in Prestashop as well as caching. Before reloading the page I am also deleting Prestashop's cache just in case, as well as I am deleting my brower's cache. Can somebody give me a hand in this?

Comment: I think this video tutorial will help you https://youtu.be/vBcXC8UbzE8 It has complete info.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
 public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
    {
      $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/adminsportsnutritionfadd.css');        
    }
```

For me it works like this:

```
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path . 'views/css/back.css');
```

So the only difference is the css file name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tested it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this sorted or not, but...

I use this function within most of my modules to add 
jQuery, Font-awesome, CSS & JS, then have it show ONLY on that module page...

```
public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader($params)
{
    if(!(Tools::getValue('controller') == 'AdminModules' 
      && Tools::getValue('configure') == 'MyModuleName')
    ){
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( method_exists($this->context->controller, 'addJquery') )
        {
            $this->context->controller->addJquery();
            $this->context->controller->addCss('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
            $this->context->controller->addCss($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
            $this->context->controller->addJs($this->_path.'views/js/back.js');
        }
    }
}
```